# Explorer.exe does not load on login, need to manually run it every time

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-explorer

Is there any solution to this. Every time I log in, I have to manually start explorer.exe from Task Manager > New Task(Run) > Explorer.exe

I am on Winodws 7 64 Bit.

Comment: What starts instead?  What caused your system to start doing this?  Was it malware?  Is your account set up as a "kiosk"?

Comment: I get a blank screen, with the base desktop color (mine is blue background)... Then I proceed to click CRTL+SHIFT+ESC to start the Task Manager and run Explorer.exe manually

Answer (score 3):

Check the Shell value for Winlogon in your registry. Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` 
should show:

```
Shell REG_SZ explorer.exe
```

Or download this tool: [Download](http://vpncasestudy.com/download/XP_logon/XP_FixLogon.zip)

This utility checks for the correct GINA value in the Registry and will allow you to restore it, if its incorrect.

try this too

Start > Run , type in   'regedit'    (without the quotes of course) in the search box .

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon.
```

In Winlogon, on the right side, there should be a value called "Shell". 
Double click this value.  Make sure only 'Explorer.exe' is the value of Shell, if anything else is there , simply delete it and leave 'Explorer.exe' . Close out the window and restart....

start>run>msconfig click on startup, make sure Explorer.exe is checked on 
See if that works..

Comment: Ran the tool, it gave the following result: http://i.cubeupload.com/ls54H3.png

Comment: Answer edited. Try the other method too

Comment: Other method also does not work... Shell value already is explorer.exe

Comment: start>run>msconfig
click on startup, make sure Explorer.exe is checked on

Comment: Done that, still no joy

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem Win 7 64 bit after a virus was cleaned from the computer. I tried many of the suggestions I found online and this is what worked for me...

Start Registry Editor (Regedit.exe) and go to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
Double-click Userinit value and change the value data to:

C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe, (or the directory where windows is installed)
Exit Regedit and reboot.

Voila... I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows 7.  Most of the answers online are like that of Unnikrishnan above.  I also tried Bryan's method, and it didn't work either.  Upgrading to Windows 10 didn't fix it.

Due to the upgrade, I searched for the solution for Windows 10, and ran into SacTekGuy's answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/explorerexe-not-starting-when-win-10-starts/af3b5f1a-d2f4-4afe-88ee-369a9771cce4?page=2).  It shed some light on the issue.  I went to this location to check:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\`

Apparently, `System` is not there.  Another round of Googling led me [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/hkeycurrentusersoftwaremicrosoftwindowscurrentvers/e2bbed76-6e35-4743-ac63-4930d6f180aa).
Carlo TJ's answer suggests using this in Command Prompt:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

I ran that, but the `System` key did not show up afterwards.  So I manually created it, and add the `Shell` string with value of `Explorer.exe` to it.  That fixed my issue.  Hope this would help others from wiping their OS out of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem in my PC. and found one solution that works for me.

Go to `Run`--> `System Configuration` ---> In `General`, select `Selective startup`, and click `Use original boot configuration`

[image: System Configuration Image-- Click Here]